# For any normal subgroup $(aN)^n=(a^n) N$ holds

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

Prove this theorem

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. If $a \in G$ and $n \in Z$, then $(aN)^n  = (a^n) N$.

I know I should prove this theorem in 3 cases where $n = 0$, $n>0$, and $n<0$. I can do the first 2 cases, but I'm not sure how to prove the third case. I wonder if anyone can help me with this part or tell me if I did any wrong.

Comment: Maybe you can show us what you tried in the case $n<0$. Recall that $-m=(-1)\cdot m$.

Comment: In the basis, we will show that (aN)^(-1)=a^(-1) N. Since
(aN)^(-1)=1/aN=1/a N=a^(-1) N,
So we have established the basis.
In the inductive step, we assume that (aN)^(-n)=a^(-n) N for some n ∈ Z^+. We will show that (aN)^(n+1)=a^(n+1)N. We know that
(aN)^(n+1)=(aN)^n (aN).
Since (aN)^n=a^n N, we can substitute the value of (aN)^n to the above equation and obtain
(aN)^(-(n+1))=1/((a^n N) ) (1/((aN) )).
Since N is a normal subgroup of G, we obtain
(aN)^(-(n+1))=1/((a^n N) ) (1/((aN) ))=1/(a^n aN)
=1/(a^(n+1) N)
=1/a^(n+1)  N
=a^(-(n+1) ) N

Comment: that was what I got but I don't know if it's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as long as you notice that $aN=Na$, the rest is easy. In details, for example, you will have $(aN)^2=(aN)(aN)=a(Na)N=a(aN)N=a^2N$, etc.

Comment: yup, I know that (aN)(bN)=(ab)N. But in this problem isn't just one ore two left coset but n of them, so I can't just say (aN)^n =(an)(aN)(aN)....(aN) , n times and got (a^n) N. I have no choice but to use the induction.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif, the point is that you can always move the $N$ to the rightmost, and calculate the elements on the left, so it doesn't matter what value the power $n$ is!

Comment: you are saying that I don't have to break in to cases where n is positive, negative and zero, but just say n is an integer, and go for it? <br/>

I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that by definition $$(bN)^{-n}=((bN)^{-1})^n$$

but $(bN)^{-1}=b^{-1}N$.

Now use what you've done before with $b=a^{-1}$, recalling that $b^{-n}:=(b^{-1})^n$

Comment: this is what I have fix from your suggestion 

In the inductive step, we assume that (aN)^(-n)=a^(-n) N for some n ∈ Z^-. We will show that (aN)^(-n+1)=a^(-n+1) N. We know that
(aN)^(-n+1)=(aN)^(-n) (aN).
Since (aN)^(-n)=a^(-n) N, we can substitute the value of (aN)^(-n) to the above equation and obtain
(aN)^(-(n+1))=(a^(-n) N)(aN).
Since N is a normal subgroup of G, we obtain
(aN)^(-n+1)=(a^(-n) N)(aN)
=(a^(-n) a)N 
=a^(-n+1) N
And now the inductive step is established.

is it look reasonable enough?

Comment: I insist that you use $(aN)^{-n}$ is defined to be $(a^{-1}N)^n$, then use your result for positive $n$, @DianeVanderwaif

Comment: thank you very much for your help